# Click on each and every radio-button of a page

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click successively on every button of the left side of [this page](http://www.specific-diets.com/product-finder/dog?PageSize=1001&SpecificDogBreedSize=4&SpecificSpecialNeeds=20).

Every radio button has a value : First one is value=4 and last one is value=32

So I thought I could just loop into those value like that :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.specific-diets.com/product-finder/dog?PageSize=1001&SpecificDogBreedSize=4&SpecificSpecialNeeds=20")



for i in range(0,32) : 
    radio=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='i']")
    radio.click()
```

I've got a problem with 'i'here or even when I put just i.  I don't know why.

If i do :

```
    radio=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='5']")
```

or

```
    radio=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='6']")
```

It perfectly works .

Why is that so ?

In addition it's not the most effective way i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do -

```
for i in range(0,32) : 
    radio=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='i']")
```

`i`'s value is not automatically substituted there, instead you are actually trying to select an element with value = `i` . Use `str.format()` instead to substitute the correct value of `i`.

Also, you should start the range from 4 till 33 , As - `range(4,33)`  as you say -

> First one is value=4 and last one is value=32

Example -

```
for i in range(4,33) : 
    radio=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='{}']".format(i))
```

Comment: Anyone care to comment why this is a bad answer? or wrong?